# AngularJs Calling function of another Controller from Another Controller

Tags: angularjs

I have two controllers, in second controller i am setting scope value using `$routeParams`, based on this value i want to execute some steps or one function in another controller based on this value.

How can I achieve this using `angularjs` ?

Answer (score 1):

While the short answer is that you can use scope inheritance to achieve this, this would be misleading and an Angular bad practice.  The correct way to do this is use a [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) (an Angular singleton) to store and retrieve data, that multiple controllers need to access. If this service also encapsulate some logic you can provide it with "private" methods and a "public" getter and setter for the info you gram from $routeParams. Notice that you need to inject the service into the controller that depend on it. Good luck.